# UpdateResource corrupts exe file

Tags: python, c++, winapi, resources, pyinstaller

I have an EXE file generated from a Python script using PyInstaller, and I've added a text file as a resource to the EXE using Resource Hacker. I'm trying to modify the resource text file programmatically using the WinAPI UpdateResource function. The modification is successful, but it causes the EXE file to become corrupted - After the modification, the EXE's size is reduced from 75 MB to 271 KB, and I can no longer run it. When I attempt to run the corrupted EXE, I receive the error message "Cannot open PyInstaller from executable."

I've tried implementing the modification using both Python and C++, but neither seems to work. Here's the Python code I've used:

Python code:

```py
exe_file = r"\path\to\exe_file.exe"
handle = win32api.BeginUpdateResource(exe_file, False)
resource_type = win32con.RT_RCDATA
new_data = "modified text".encode()
try:
    win32api.UpdateResource(handle, resource_type, 110, new_data)

    # Save the changes and close the file
    win32api.EndUpdateResource(handle, False)
except:
    win32api.EndUpdateResource(handle, True)
```

This is the C++ code (I handled in my actual code the cases when handles are invalid, but if I put it all here, the code gets much longer):

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <winuser.h>


int modify_resource(const LPCWSTR new_text, const LPCWSTR filename)
{
    const LPCWSTR res_type = MAKEINTRESOURCE(RT_RCDATA);
    const LPCWSTR res_name = MAKEINTRESOURCE(110); // resource ID

    HMODULE module = LoadLibraryEx(filename, NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
    HRSRC res_info = FindResource(module, res_name, res_type);

    DWORD res_size = SizeofResource(module, res_info);
    HGLOBAL res_data = LoadResource(module, res_info);

    LPVOID res_ptr = LockResource(res_data);
    FreeResource(res_data);
    HANDLE update_handle = BeginUpdateResource(filename, FALSE);

    BOOL result = UpdateResource(update_handle, res_type, res_name, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL), (LPVOID)new_text, (DWORD)(wcslen(new_text) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));
    if (!result)
    {
        EndUpdateResource(update_handle, TRUE);
        FreeLibrary(module);
        return 1;
    }

    result = EndUpdateResource(update_handle, FALSE);
    FreeLibrary(module);
    if (!result)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to find why this happens, or at least find another way to modify the resource text file. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**:
Here are minimal reproduction steps: convert the following python program to exe:

```py
input("Press enter to exit")
```

With the pyinstaller command: `pyinstaller --onefile --console <script_name.py>`

and run the following c++ code:

```cpp
# include <windows.h>
# define RES_ID 110

int main();
{
    const LPCWSTR res_type = MAKEINTRESOURCE(RT_RCDATA);
    const LPCWSTR res_name = MAKEINTRESOURCE(RES_ID);
    HMODULE module = LoadLibrary(L"exe\\to\\copy\\resource\\from.exe");
    HRSRC res_info = FindResource(module, res_name, res_type);
    HGLOBAL res_load = LoadResource(module, res_info);
    LPVOID res_ptr = LockResource(res_load);

    HANDLE update_handle = BeginUpdateResource(L"path\\to\\python\\exe.exe", FALSE);
    DWORD res_size = SizeofResource(module, res_info);

    BOOL result = UpdateResource(update_handle,
        res_type,
        res_name,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL),
        res_ptr,
        res_size);

    EndUpdateResource(update_handle, FALSE);
    FreeLibrary(module);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the PE file that PyInstaller creates isn't 100% correct or up-to-spec?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with [Updating Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-resources#updating-resources). Can your executable *filename* be loaded by `LoadLibraryEx`? Why did your executable attempt to open `PyInstaller`?

Comment: There are some cases in which `Pyinstaller` opens when I run the executable (e.g. when there are missing imports). I am not sure if the executable is intended to be opened by `LoadLibraryEx` (when I open the executable with `LoadLibrary` I get the error ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT : %1 is not a valid Win32 application)

Comment: In the example code in [Updating Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-resources) they are using LoadLibrary, but since I am loading an executable, I am using LoadLibraryEx with the LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE flag. I assume that the fact that it manages to modify the resource means that it indeed loads the executable.

Comment: I was suspecting that it was the big size of the executable (75 MB), so I tried it with Microsoft Team (which is 100 MB), and everything went fine. I also took anotehr smaller exe (15 MB) which was also made with `Pyinstaller` - and it was also shrinked (to 270 KB) and got corrupted. So for the moment the suspicion falls on `Pyinstaller`. Is there a known issue with `Pyinstaller`?

Comment: NO. [BeginUpdateResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-beginupdateresourcea) doesn't load but open. In consideration of `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT`, does the architecture of your application which calling `LoadLibraryEx` match with the architecture of `the executable` to load? Can *Resource Hacker* modify safely? Maybe you need turning to `Pyinstaller` support?

Comment: Resource hacker modifies the resource safely somehow. Does it use another method to do so?

Comment: I've added minimal reproduction steps

Comment: I cant find the contact of Pyinstaller support. Does anyone know who can I contact with regarding this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-reading your question I now get what you want to do: you already have the PyInstaller file (you are not generating it yourself), and you want to change it after the fact.

This should be possible, by first separating the pure PE part of the executable from the rest (which is the archive that was appended to it), then modifying the pure PE part, and then re-appending the rest.

I've written a small Python function that will do just that:

```py
import os, time
import pefile
import win32api, win32con
from PyInstaller.utils.win32 import winutils

def modify_pyinstaller(exe_file):
    modified_name = exe_file.removesuffix('.exe') + '_modified.exe'

    size = 0
    with pefile.PE(exe_file, fast_load=True) as pe:
        size = pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.SizeOfHeaders
        for section in pe.sections:
            size += section.SizeOfRawData

    # Copy just the initial .exe part
    with open(exe_file, 'rb') as fin, open(modified_name, 'wb') as fout:
        fout.write(fin.read(size))

    # This part of the code is from what you wanted to do with
    # the executable...
    handle = win32api.BeginUpdateResource(modified_name, False)
    try:
        win32api.UpdateResource(handle, win32con.RT_RCDATA, 110, "modified text".encode())
        win32api.EndUpdateResource(handle, False)
    except:
        win32api.EndUpdateResource(handle, True)
        raise
    # End of the part that should be modified...

    # Now that we've modified the exe, copy the archive back (the rest of the original file)
    # (note the 'ab' mode to append data)
    with open(exe_file, 'rb') as fin, open(modified_name, 'ab') as fout:
        fin.seek(size, os.SEEK_SET)
        fout.write(fin.read())

    # Now that we're done also keep virus scanners happy and update
    # the timestamps and PE checksums. Re-use PyInstaller's
    # implementation, because they already figured this out.
    # (Note that since we're now using PyInstaller's functionality
    # here, this will technically make this code GPL-2+, because
    # that's the license of PyInstaller!)
    winutils.set_exe_build_timestamp(modified_name, int(time.time()))
    winutils.update_exe_pe_checksum(modified_name)
```

The general logic is the following:

- It uses the `pefile` package to extract the size of the executable part of the file, without the embedded archive (stores that in `size`)
- It then creates a copy of the original file, but only the first `size` bytes (to only copy the executable)
- It then performs the modifications that you want to do (please replace that part of the code)
- It then **appends** the rest of the contents of the original file (starting at `size` bytes offset into the original file) onto the modified file
- Because PyInstaller also does it, it updates the time stamp and the PE checksum of the newly generated file (to keep virus scanners happy) - I've imported PyInstaller for that and called their functionality here (otherwise you'd have to reimplement that)  (you could technically skip this part if you just want a working .exe)
- You don't have to understand what kind of format the archive is at all, you just have to copy the data

At least with a trivial hello world Python script this appears to work for me, and it should work in the general case (with any self-extracting PE executable really, not just those generated by PyInstaller), but your mileage may vary.

You can probably optimize this a bit more (I'm currently reading the entire data into memory before writing it out again), but the code should illustrate the principle.

**Disclaimer:** please *only* do this if you can't recreate the PyInstaller file yourself. If you are creating the installer file anyway, the PyInstaller developers have already added the required functionality to add resources during the build process. (See my other answer to this question for details.)

Comment: Amazing!! it works like magic! Thank you very much for your dedication and help! I am looking for the c++ equivalent for that. Do you know of a c++ library that I can use to load the pe file and extract the size of the executable (like the pefile module in python)?

Answer (score 1):

The actual executable from PyInstaller is less than 300 kiB in size. It is present in the Git repository and can be found in the [PyInstaller/bootloader/[operating system]](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tree/develop/PyInstaller/bootloader/Windows-64bit-intel) subdirectory.

What PyInstaller does while building the installer is that it does all sorts of complex things to figure out what to package, creates an archive of those files, and appends the archive to the executable itself.

When calling the executable it will unpack the archive that is part of the own executable into a temporary directory, and then runs the actual implementation of PyInstaller (which itself is written in Python) from that temporary directory. The executable itself is called the **bootloader** by the PyInstaller people. What the bootloader does exactly is explained in the [corresponding PyInstaller documentation](https://pyinstaller.org/en/v5.11.0/advanced-topics.html#the-bootstrap-process-in-detail).

If you now take a thusly generated executable and use standard Windows API functions to edit it, those functions will only see the initial bootloader part of the executable, and not see the archive that was appended. And for this reason, when they rewrite the executable back to disk, they will rewrite only the executable portion, and not the archive.

Since the archive contains both PyInstaller code as well as the code that was meant to be packaged, and the bootloader is just a very simple program (on purpose), the bootloader will fail because it can't find anything to do with itself.

To modify resources in a PyInstaller file you would need to add those resources during the build process of PyInstaller, **before** the archive is added to the bootloader by the builder.

Fortunately for you, the PyInstaller people have already thought of this, and have added the [`-r` command line option](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-r) to the installer, so you could easily use

```
pyinstaller -r file_with_resources.res your_script.py
```

instead of just

```
pyinstaller your_script.py
```

This will automatically add the resources from the specified resource file to the generated installer and should achieve what you want.

Comment: Frankly, I could not believe this, so I skimmed through the PyInstaller source. And it seems that you are correct: PyInstaller generates invalid PE images, and when using official system API calls, things just break. This is horrible, no matter how you slice it. I wonder how you'd sign a PyInstaller-generated EXE, given that there's no way to embed the certificate without breaking the bootloader's assumptions. I'm still dearly hoping that I simply misinterpreted the code I'd seen.

Comment: @Iinspectable This is nothing new. Since as far back as I can remember in the '90s were self-extracting installers generated this way - think e.g. WinZIP, WinRAR, etc. I haven't tried, but I suspect programs such as 7zip still work that way. If you attempted to edit the executables in the same manner, the same thing would happen as in the PyInstaller case. Funnily enough, signtool works in such a manner that it **can** handle this additional data - I just tried signing a PyInstaller-generated file and that worked, and modifying the non-exe part (hex editor) resulted in an invalid signature.

Comment: Wow! I am impressed by how you found the cause for this problem! I contacted the creator of Resource Hacker and he said that he modified the resource by manually rebuilding the resource section (but he doesn't remember exactly how he did it). Does it mean than that there is no way (other than modifying the whole resource section) to modify a Pyinstaller exe?

Comment: @Roey_MR What do you mean 'modifying the whole resource section'? The ``'-r`` option for the PyInstaller will copy over any resources from the specified file (can also be another ``.exe``), but as far as I remember from skimming the source code it doesn't remove the existing resources, it just adds/updates the new ones. So this should work for your use case, unless I'm missing and/or misremembering something?